# C# TimeSpan calculating hours

Tags: c#, timespan

I am trying to create a time card solution in C# and having an issue with totaling hours worked for a week.  From a drop down, the user would select the number of hours they worked in a day (ex. 5:30 - the 5:30 is the total hours worked, not the actual time 5:30).  The user would select the hours each work day and the application would then total the hours for the week.  The application I have written totals the hours, but I have two issues: if I use .Hours to add the hours up, I run into an issue when the total goes over 24; when I use .TotalHours, it calculates over 24 ok, but somehow it adds an hour randomly when I select :30 increments.  Here is the code I have to calculate and display the totals:

using .Hours does not allow the total number of hours to go over 24.  Instead it converts the 24 to 1 day and starts the adding the hours again, losing the original 24:

```
lblWorkgroupOneTotalTime.Text = (totalWeekOneHours.Hours).ToString("00") + 
                        ":" + (totalWeekOneHours.Minutes).ToString("00");

//using .TotalHours causes the calculation to randomly add an hour to the total:

lblWorkgroupTwoTotalTime.Text =
  (totalWeekTwoHours.TotalHours).ToString("00").TrimStart('0') + 
  ":" + (totalWeekTwoHours.Minutes).ToString("00");
```

I feel like I am very close to having everything work correctly, but I can't figure this part out.

Comment: I would use a `TimeSpan` and use `TotalMinutes / 60` for hours and `TotalMinutes % 60` for minutes.

Comment: I don't think I could get the time to calculate as a string.  I have them as TimeSpan and then total the hours, but when it gets calculated, that is when I have the issue.  I put them into the label via the ToString.  The errors happen during the calculation.  When the user selects the time from the dropdown, all is well.  But when I calculate the hours selected, I run into the issues.

Comment: The user will select predetermined times in 15 min increments from a drop down (0:15, 0:30, 0:45, 1:00, 1:15 etc).  This was done to limit the bad input the user could enter.  Once they have selected the time(s), then I perform the calculations.  The times are TimeSpan

Comment: Any ideas why, when using .TotalHours, the calculations add an hour when selecting times ending in :30?  The additional hour is added when the total time added up ends in :30.  So 1:00 + :30 comes out to 2:30, but if I were to add another :30, it totals 2:00.  Weird.

Comment: It's doing that because you're formatting the string to not include the decimal point, so it's rounding up. You can use `Hours` instead, but you will also have to add `Days * 24` to it.

Comment: The solution I have used in the past is to figure out TimeSpan per day and save as a _Decimal_ representation (1.5 decimal  = 1:30). For whatever period you can sum it up and then multiply the decimal portion * 60 to get minutes

Comment: When I use the Hours, it works fine, except when it comes to the over 24 hours issue.  So if an employee works over 24 hours in a week, it does not calculate that correctly.  I don't want days included in the calculation or display, I am looking to display just the hours and minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with displaying `TotalHours` with a format string of `"00"` is that it's going to round up. You have a couple of choices if you don't want to show days:

1. Use `Hours` + `Days * 24` for the hours
2. Use `TotalMinutes / 60` for hours
3. Convert `TotalHours` to an `int`, which will always round down

For example:

```
var totalHours = (totalWeekOneHours.Days * 24) + totalWeekOneHours.Hours;
// Or:
var totalHours = totalWeekOneHours.TotalMinutes / 60;
// Or:
var totalHours = (int)totalWeekOneHours.TotalHours;
```

Then you can output it:

```
lblWorkgroupOneTotalTime.Text = $"{totalHours:00}:{totalWeekOneHours.Minutes:00}";
```

Comment: How can I change the format so the rounding isn't an issue?  I tried your suggestions, but could not get it to work - yet.  So I was wondering if you had a suggestion on how to address the rounding issue by changing the format.

Comment: convert it to an `int` and it will round down. I'll update the answer...

Answer (score 0):

How about this:
Initialize an example for 30 hours and 30 minutes:

```
TimeSpan totalWeekThreeHours = new TimeSpan(30, 30, 0);
```

(Timespan works better than DateTime here I feel.)

Then:

```
var hours = (int)totalWeekThreeHours.TotalMinutes / 60;
var mins = totalWeekThreeHours.TotalMinutes % 60;
```

Output:

```
var example1 = hours + ":" + mins;
var example2 = String.Format("{0} hours {1} mins", hours, mins);
Console.WriteLine("Example 1: " + example1);
Console.WriteLine("Example 2: " + example2);

//Output:
//Example 1: 30:30
//Example2: 30 hours 30 minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

> it adds an hour randomly

Nothing in programming happens "randomly". So when debugging, your first step should always be to look for patterns in your bug. As long as you believe the bug happens "randomly", you will have a mental block getting in the way of finding the bug.

As for your specific issue…

For any of the `Total...` properties of `TimeSpan`, this will be a `double` value that represents the *entire* time span in the units you're retrieving, including any fractional amounts.

For example, if the `TimeSpan` value represents 1 hour and 45 minutes, the `TotalHours` value will be `1.75`. At the same time, you are telling the `ToString()` method that you want the value rounded to the nearest integer value. So, any time that the fractional part of your time span in hours is greater than one-half, the value is rounded up to the next hour value.

If you don't want that behavior, you should just truncate the value yourself before formatting it as a string:

```
lblWorkgroupTwoTotalTime.Text = string.Format("{0:0}:{1:00}",
  (int)totalWeekTwoHours.TotalHours, totalWeekTwoHours.Minutes);
```

I also don't see why you used the format string `"00"` only to strip off the leading `0` after the fact. Easier to just not format the string that way in the first place.

Finally, note alternative syntax for formatting strings. Your approach (calling `ToString()` explicitly) is fine, but I find it wordy. The above is more concise, and does a better job separating the *format* from the input *values*.

Comment: Great feedback, thank you!!  I am pretty new to programming so I greatly appreciate the information.  And, more importantly, your solution worked!!!!